# How to add the property pInitEditableRow of p-table in the Menu Items defined in TypeScript to allow the editing of row in the DataTable?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

This is My HTML:-

```
<td *ngIf="!editing" class="more">
                  <div class="displayFlex flexJustifyEnd">
                    <p-button  (onClick)="toggleMenu(menu, $event,role)" styleClass="p-button-text"><i
                        class="icon icon-more-vertical"></i>
                    </p-button>
                  </div>
                  <p-menu appendTo="body" #menu [popup]="true" [model]="items"></p-menu>
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="editing" style="text-align:center" class="displayFlex flexJustifyEnd">
                  <button pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" class="ui-button-success"
                    style="margin-right: .5em" (click)="onRowEditSave(role)"></button>
                  <button pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger"
                    (click)="onRowEditCancel(role, ri)"></button>
                </td>
```

This is My ts file:-

```
toggleMenu(menu: Menu, event, role: Role) {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Edit Role', icon: 'pi pi-pencil', command: () => {
          this.onRowEditInit(role);
        }
      }
    ]
    menu.toggle(event);
  }
```

I would like to add the property "pInitEditableRow" of PrimeNG only when I click on the Edit Role Menu Item how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
@ViewChild('dt') table: Table;

addRegistroRow() {
 this.table.value.unshift(new cAutBolsaAplicacion(33333));
 this.table.initRowEdit(this.table.value[0])
}
```

```html
<p-table editMode="row" #dt></p-table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).